# Jboss 4.2.2 java.rmi.ExportException

Tags: port, jboss-4.2.x

i get the following exception when i run Jboss 4.2.2

```
Reason: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 1098; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
```

I checked with TCP view. port 1098 is being used by another process on my machine. There must be a way to change the port numbers for a process. But I am unaware about it.

Comment: From JBoss Forum: https://community.jboss.org/thread/59995

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process holding the 1098 port

or just "Close connection" for that port with TCPView

or change ports in JBoss:

http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/JBoss+Ports  (domain name changed by wiki owner)

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine